# Azure SQL Datawarehouse - Pagination

Tags: azure-synapse

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#Offset

As per this article, we dont have Pagination ( Offset) while using Azure SQL datawarehouse. Is there any other alternative to attain without loosing the performance. I investigated on ROW_NUMBER() but hitting with Temp table issue as it tries to create temp table for each execution.

Considering this, hoping that it might not be solution for large usage.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Below is generating the Temp Issue. 
There is already an object named 'QTable_afe4f02abd464b7cb30e0c70a06d65be' in the database.
Again, deleting the re-creating temp table might not be feasible as this is exposed through API's which would be used by large number of clients

```
SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT
           A.Col1, A.Col2
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1 DESC) AS RowNum
        FROM table1 A
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 B ON B.Col1 = A.Col1
    ) AS OrderedOutput
    WHERE OrderedOutput.RowNum BETWEEN @startRow AND @endRow
```

Looking for alternative of OFFSET and FETCH.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? We are using the ROW_NUMBER OVER similiar to you - but this causes either a SHUFFLE or COMUTE_TO_CONTROL_NODE I guess because all the data on all the nodes need to be joined and sorted before returning to client.